# What is the default width/margin/padding of SVG <g> and <text> elements?

Tags: html, css, text, svg, width

I have the following SVG file I am working on.
http://jsfiddle.net/slayerofgiants/9y3qc/8/

If you notice from the fiddle file, the horizontal scrollbar extends to about twice the width of the SVG drawing.  There is nothing but white space beyond the edge of the SVG.  If I remove the `<g>` and `<text>` elements, then horizontal scrollbar goes away and is the size of the width of the screen.

You can see this on this 2nd jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/slayerofgiants/m5zPv/

The code below is the SVG with no `g` elements containing the paired `text` elements.

```
<svg version="1.1" width="90%" id="ex1-3rds-quarter-s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
 y="0px"  viewBox="0 0 323.333 55.333" enable-background="new 0 0 323.333 55.333"
 xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
     <font horiz-adv-x="1000">
<g id="fullTAB"  transform="scale(1.1,1)"  >
<g id="tablines" display="block">
        <line fill="none" id="lowE" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="6" y1="45" x2="262" y2="45"/>
        <line fill="none" id="Astring" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="6" y1="38.5" x2="262" y2="38.5"/>
        <line fill="none" id="Dstring" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="6" y1="32" x2="262" y2="32"/>
        <line fill="none" id="Gstring" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="6" y1="25.5" x2="262" y2="25.5"/>
        <line fill="none" id="Bstring" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="6" y1="19" x2="262" y2="19"/>
        <line fill="none" id="highE" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x1="6" y1="12.5" x2="262" y2="12.5"/>
</g>
<rect x="258" y="12" display="inline" width="0.829" height="32.73"/>
<rect x="260" y="12" display="inline" width="2.618" height="32.73"/>
<rect x="78" y="12" display="inline" width="0.829" height="32.73"/>
<rect x="6" y="12" display="inline" width="1" height="32.73"/>
<rect x="204" y="12" display="inline" width="0.829" height="32.73"/>
<rect x="142" y="12" display="inline" width="0.829" height="32.73"/>
<text x="13" y="21" style="text-anchor: middle" display="inline" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="8.3685">T</text>
<text x="13" y="31" style="text-anchor: middle" display="inline" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="8.3685">A</text>
<text x="13" y="41" style="text-anchor: middle" display="inline" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="8.3685">B</text>
<g id="fretinformation">    

</g><!--Fret Information -->
</g><!--Full Tab -->
</svg>
```

The code below is the `g` element with the paired `text` elements I am using which when inserted into the document causes the scrollbar to extend to about twice the width of the drawing size.  I have a number of these with different x values. They are in the `#fretinformation` `g` element which is empty in the code above.

```
<g display="inline">
    <text x="248" y="35" style="text-anchor: middle" fill="#324DCE" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="8.3685">2</text>
    <text x="248" y="41.5" style="text-anchor: middle" fill="#324DCE" font-family="'MyriadPro-Bold'" font-size="8.3685">3</text>
</g>
```

I had thought the `g` element had no width value and the text element width would collapse to only the width of the text it contained.  What are the default `widths/margin/padding` of the `g` and `text` elements?  And how can I change this behavior so there is no horizontal scrollbar?
Thanks--Christopher

**EDIT**
What appears to be happening is the `text` element is getting a width of 90% of the window size and as the text element is transformed along the x axis, it increases the overall width of the SVG file to be almost twice what it should be.  As I remove text elements from right to left, the amount of whitespace to the right of the SVG file decreases.

Comment: viewbox attribute hides what overflows your SVG, but it is still there and handled different from a browser to another when inline document. it is suppose to behave as an inline-boxe alike object or img.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is render as an inline-boxe without any extra padding or margins**.

I noticed a bug in chrome and another in IE11. wich one bothers you ?

It is somehow a bug that you can fix with : `height:1%;`*(chrome)* and `overflow:hidden`*(IE)* in your case : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9y3qc/10/)**

```
svg {
    display:block;
    border:solid;
    width:90%;
    height:1%; /* fix webkit */
    overflow:hidden;/* fix IE */
}
```

jsfiddle re-edited from IE11 : http://jsfiddle.net/9y3qc/13/ to check once again your comment
[image: svg not overflowing in Ie11]

Comment: I am actually using internet explorer 11.  Looking at your link, I still see a horizontal scroll bar which is about twice the width of the svg drawing.  Adding the height attribute did not fix the problem.  The problem has something to do with the width of either the g element or the text element.

Comment: ah i see , another bug different from Chrome, the way to fix it is to add : overflow:hidden to svg. http://jsfiddle.net/9y3qc/10/

Comment: the overflow:hidden does work, however, it does not answer the question of what the default width of the svg text element is nor does it answer how to set or change that width.

Comment: @ChristopherGaston so clarify your question : screenshot, wich browser , what code used . **http://jsfiddle.net/9y3qc/10/ produces for me no scroll inIE11, Chrome , Firefox, Opera latest version**. did you really check it ?

Comment: I did try the `overflow:hidden` and it does remove the horizontal scroll bar, however it introduces other problems.  My image is resized dynamically and is swapped between two primary blocks of svg elements.  With the `overflow:hidden' option, the whole image is no longer dynamic in resizing and other parts of the image are now extending beyond the viewplane and are no longer visible.  Is there any other option for collapsing the width of the text element so that it is only the size of the text it contains?

Comment: @ChristopherGaston  Hello, i do not follow you anymore, your fiddle has one SVG to wich the overflow is set . attribute viewbox gives it a size ( if <text> is set out this area or bigger, whole or  part of it will be hidden ) , so it can rescale. You tell me about text and image, are these inside SVG or is it other HTML element or text aside in your document ? can you set a new fiddle with what you are having trouble now ?

Comment: My jsfiddle was simplified for this question.  The whole project is quite complex.  Here is a link to the fiddle of the big project I have so far.  http://jsfiddle.net/slayerofgiants/DRBr2/1/ With the staff showing, if you change the key to Gb, you will see where it extends past the viewport when the `overflow:hidden` is present in the css.

Comment: @ChristopherGaston , i increased width of viewbox , so all mesures are seen : http://jsfiddle.net/DRBr2/4/ I do still have no scrollbar in IE11. Sorry , i might not understand what is your trouble.

Comment: okay, i see it now on bigger resolution. you need to increase the viewbox height too  and reposition tabs/mesure a little lower so you have room from top to bottom to show higher and lower notes. Firefox applies the overflow:hidden by default.

Answer (score 10):

`SVG` does not use a `box layout model` like `HTML`/`CSS`.

Putting `display="inline"` on an `SVG` element is basically meaningless.  SVG elements are *placed and drawn where you explicitly tell them*.

The thing that determines the width and height of an SVG document is the `width` and `height` attributes (and sometimes the `viewBox`) of the root `<svg>` element.

However there are some differences (ie. bugs) in the way browsers lay out SVG elements.  The fact that you are getting a scrollbar is an IE bug.  You can use GCyrillus' overflow hidden trick to fix that.